# How to concate a column's sentences for same subject id in a single row in python dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

if I have a dataset like-

```
Subject_ID           DRUG                         LOS
     2456          Syringe (Neonatal) *NS*        1.56
     2456          Heparin                        1.56
     12345         Syringe (Neonatal) *NS*        0.78
     12345         ampicillin                     0.78
     12345         gentamicin                     0.78
```

As output, I want that the Drug name with the same Subject_ID will concatenate in one row.

```
Subject_ID                 DRUG                                       LOS
     2456          Syringe (Neonatal) *NS*, Heparin                    1.56                                
     12345         Syringe (Neonatal) *NS*, ampicillin, gentamicin     0.78
```

How can I do that in Python pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group the dataframe by `Subject_ID` then call `agg` with `', '.join` as aggregate for `DRUG` column, and `first` as aggregate for `LOS` column.

```py
>>> df.groupby(['Subject_ID']).agg({'DRUG':', '.join, 'LOS':'first'})

                                                       DRUG   LOS
Subject_ID                                                       
2456                       Syringe (Neonatal) *NS*, Heparin  1.56
12345       Syringe (Neonatal) *NS*, ampicillin, gentamicin  0.78
```